# Aurelia Validation abstracted to Model

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have followed Scott Allen's Aurelia Pluralsight course which makes use of the Aurelia-Validation plugin.

This results in a view-model edit.js:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {MovieService} from "./movieService";
import {Router} from "aurelia-router";
import {Validation} from "aurelia-validation";

@inject(MovieService, Router, Validation)
export class Edit {

    constructor(movieService, router, validation) {
        this.service = movieService;
        this.router = router;
        this.validation = validation.on(this)
        .ensure("movie.title").isNotEmpty().hasLengthBetween(3, 50)
        .ensure("movie.releaseYear").isNotEmpty().isNumber().isBetween(1900, 2100)
        .ensure("movie.starRating").isNotEmpty().isNumber().isBetween(0, 5);
    }

    activate(params) {
        this.service.getById(params.id)
            .then(movie => {
                this.movie = movie;
           });
    }

    save() {
        this.validation.validate()
            .then(() => {
                this.service.save(this.movie)
                    .then(movie => {
                        let url = this.router.generate("home");
                        this.router.navigate(url);
                    });
            })
            .catch(() => {
            });
    }

}
```

And a view edit.html

```
                <form class="form-horizontal"
                      validate.bind="validation"
                      submit.trigger="save()">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="title">Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" value.bind="movie.title" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="rating">Rating</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="rating" placeholder="Rating" value.bind="movie.starRating" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="releaseYear">Release Year</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="releaseYear" placeholder="Release Year" value.bind="movie.releaseYear" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <a route-href="route:home" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Cancel</a>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                    </div>

                </form>
```

This works as expected with the validation preventing invalid data from being submitted.

What I would like to do next is to abstract the validation rules out from the view model and into a model class.  I have created a model movieModel.js

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {ensure} from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(Validation)
export class MovieModel {

    @ensure(function(it){ it.isNotEmpty().hasLengthBetween(3, 50) })
    title = "";

    @ensure(function(it){ it.isNotEmpty().isNumber().isBetween(1900, 2100) })
    releaseYear = "";

    @ensure(function(it){ it.isNotEmpty().isNumber().isBetween(0, 5) })
    starRating = "";

    constructor(validation) {
        this.title = "";
        this.releaseYear = "";
        this.starRating = "";
    }
}
```

And made use of it in the view model like this:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {MovieService} from "./movieService";
import {Router} from "aurelia-router";
import {Validation} from "aurelia-validation";
import {MovieModel} from "./movieModel";

@inject(MovieService, Router, Validation, MovieModel)
export class Edit {

    constructor(movieService, router, validation, movieModel) {
        this.service = movieService;
        this.router = router;
        this.movie = movieModel;
        this.validation = validation.on(this.movie);
    }

    activate(params) {
        this.service.getById(params.id)
            .then(movie => {
                this.movie = movie;
           });
    }

    save() {
        this.validation.validate()
            .then(() => {
                this.service.save(this.movie)
                    .then(movie => {
                        let url = this.router.generate("home");
                        this.router.navigate(url);
                    });
            })
            .catch(() => {
            });
    }

}
```

Changes to the view edit.html are just adding the validate attribute to the input fields e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" value.bind="movie.title" class="form-control"/>
```

becomes

```
<input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" value.bind="movie.title" validate="title" class="form-control"/>
```

However, when I edit a movie retrieved from the service via the activate() function and then attempt to save it, the validation flags all the properties as "is required".

I assume the statement this.validation = validation.on(this.movie) in the constructor of the view model is tying the validation to a non-populated instance of the model but I have no idea how to overcome this.

Comment: "I have followed Jon Skeets Aurelia Pluralsight course"... Hey, shouldn't that be K. Scott Allen's course? :)

Comment: ooops - sorry Scott!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create validation every time your model is changed

```
activate(params) {
    this.service.getById(params.id)
        .then(movie => {
            this.movie = movie;
            this.validation = this.Validation.on(this.movie);
       });
}
```

UPDATE: and in constructor

```
this.Validation = validation;
```

Comment: I understand your reasoning and figured I must be missing something very simple.  However, I have tried amending the activate() function to include `this.validation = this.Validation.on(this.movie);` but I get an error "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined(…)  I also then tried `this.validation = this.validation.on(this.movie);` (lowercase v) but get the error "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: _this.validation.on is not a function"

Comment: sure, because in constructor you need to write `this.Validation = validation;` to have link to the Validation singleton, so then you can use `this.Validation`

Comment: ok - so the adding `this.validation = this.validation.on(this.movie);` to the activate() function no longer errors.  However, saving of invalid data is not prevented.  Is this because `this.movie` is retrieved from the service and has no knowledge of the validation rules in MovieModel?

Comment: yes, if you get json from service you need to create MovieModel and fill it with recieved data.

Comment: But, as for me, I don't like `@ensure(...) title = "";` syntax because you will get in trouble when you need to validate complex objects, like you have `{name: "", address: {street: "", locality: ""}}` and you need to validate `address.street` or even worse when you have array of objects to validate, it can go really hard to make things work. So in the first example you just have more control though it is not so "beautiful"